# Sudden shift in color of a linear gradient in center

Tags: android, android-drawable, linear-gradients

I am trying to achieve the behavior, shown in image below, using xml. Note that the color is shifting suddenly in the middle, instead of a gradual shift of color. I assumed that this could be achieved using gradient but I cannot figure out how. Is there a way to achieve it using gradient or any other way using xml?

Here is what my current xml code looks like:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#E86D52"
        android:startColor="#E11E26" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1.5dp"
        android:color="#231F20" />
</shape>
```

Here is the sample image of what I want to achieve but don't know how:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set angle to set horizontal and vertical gradient and stroke color for border. Following is example of gradient xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#c1c1c1"
                android:endColor="#4f4f4f"
                android:gradientRadius="400"
                android:startColor="#c1c1c1"
                android:angle="180"
                />
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>

            <stroke android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/yellow"/>


            <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Let suppose your gradient is "bg_button.xml".You will use as-

```
 <Button

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
                       android:text="Next"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                      android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text" />
```

Comment: The requirement is not as the answer.  Your answer will give a nice gradient button :)

Comment: @BugsHappen Can you post your Xml which you are using

Comment: @Manishika I've updated my question, please check the xml code

Comment: I just tried your XML and it does not have any sudden shift of color.

Comment: I know it doesn't. I want to achieve this sudden shift affect. How can I achieve it? That's my question.